# Creating a UITouch object

Tags: instantiation, uitouch

In my iPhone app I'm overriding the `touchesBegan:withEvent` method in my view and what I want to do is make some tweaks to the UITouch object found in the NSSet and send it to another view. I couldn't find anywhere how to create a UITouch object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I got it to work was by categorizing the UITouch and create an init method. This blog should explain how to do it:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/synthesizing-touch-event-on-iphone.html

Comment: Warning: this is not a very app store friendly approach. Your app may well get rejected if it contains this category!

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work for iOS 7 anymore. It won't eighter complile! Is there a work arround for this? I'd really like to integrate that fancy stuff.

Comment: "Me,too" with NicTesla -- got the whole `SelfTesting` project from CocoaWithLove, but it's got dozens of compile errors just out of the box.  Looks like we don't have access to UITouch's iVars, anymore (so, for example, in `initInView:`, the line `_tapCount = 1;` is an error: use of undeclared identifier.  There are many-many more of these.

Comment: NOTE: after much Google/SO/etc., learning, I found a way to set the `_tapCount` and other variables using `getIvarPointer` and KVO.  None of it's very pretty, but it works.

Comment: Hi Olie, can you share with us how you achieved this? we are also trying to achieve something similar and was thinking of utilizing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028734/how-to-programmatically-fake-a-touch-event-to-a-uibutton to create UItouch object

Comment: @Olie, can you post your solution please?

Comment: I can't post my solution-code, for contractual reasons (it was work-for-hire; not my IP.)  However, the blog linked gives the solution; I only had to make minor changes (defining some variables, if I recall.)  I'm sorry -- I know SO is meant to be the place to copy/paste answers, but I can't.  :\