# How to trigger an IBAction method programmatically vs. via a button, etc?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, model-view-controller, interface-builder, nswindow

I can easily "do something", by creating an IBAction method,  and connecting it to a button in IB.  For example...

```
-(IBAction)popThat:(id)sndr{ [windy setFrame:eRect display:YES];}
```

However, I cannot, *for the life of me*, figure out how to do this via a **simple, callable method**... i.e.

```
-(void) popThatMethod { [windy setFrame:eRect display:YES]; }

-(void) awakeFromNib  { [self popThatMethod];               }
```

I would *expect* that this method would DO the same thing as clicking the button... as they are identical... *but NO*. Nothing happens.  **What am I missing here?**

Comment: It could be possible that you calling it too early. Try calling it from `applicationDidFinishLaunching` or `windowDidLoad` instead

Comment: I have tried it inside `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification` to no avail.

Comment: You don't need to do a separate method either, just call the IBAction returning method with `[self popWindowMethod:self];`

Comment: You'd need to call the method once the window (and it's view tree) have been displayed, otherwise you are making calls and setting sizes of frames in and based on nothing as the layout will be deferred until they are visible, not loaded.

Comment: @twilson Isn't that the point of `applicationDidFinishLaunching`?  If i create a method, one that simply contains `[self popWindow:self]` and call it from `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, there is still no result..

Comment: What is `popWindowMethod` actually trying to achieve?

Comment: `popWindowMethod` is just trying to do the same thing as `popWindow`... without having to CLICK on something to do it... (all `popWindow` does is resize / animate the current window - to the full size of the screen) it's not pseudo-code.. try it, it works.

Comment: This (the window maximizing, in windows parlance) is the result I get. Try setting a breakpoint on `[self popWindowMethod];` to see if execution makes it to that line.

Comment: @barfoon Don't manipulate NSViews from a background thread.  That will take you for a ride on the pain train destined for the hurt locker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't state that this is categorically the best answer, or the right way to do it, but one approach that works is to put the following in `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:`:

```
[self performSelector: @selector(popWindow:) withObject:self afterDelay: 0.0];
```

This causes it to be called on the next pass of the runloop, by which time whatever was not in place before is now in place.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you're trying to do, you might want

```
[buttonObj sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Which triggers the button as if it had been touched, and forces whatever actions are connected to it.

NOTE: that's the answer from when I asked [this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028734/how-to-programmatically-fake-a-touch-event-to-a-uibutton/4034034#4034034)

Comment: Not sure... but this sounds similar to `[button performClick];`, which is what I have been using on Mac buttons.