# How to pass UIAction without touching the UIButton

Tags: iphone, uibutton, ibaction

I've got a UIButton that acts as a switch. 
When user taps on it, its state changes to "selected" and action "one" is called. When user taps again UIButton state changes to "not selected" and the action is no longer available.

Is there a way to set the UIButton to "selected" by taping on a completely different UIButton and have it change to "selected" and call the same action as well?

Cheers

Comment: plzz give a clear description of your question

Comment: You means you want to call same method to two different button tap. Right?

Comment: So you want to have faked touch event like here: [how to programmatically fake a touch event to a UIButton?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4034034/593709)

Comment: Thanks Adil. This is what I was looking for.did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have understood from the question, I would like to give you my suggestion

```
if (!<your_button>.selected)
{
    <your_button>.selected = YES;
    // do your stuff here
}
else
{
    <your_button>.selected = NO;
    // do your stuff here, in your case action should be no longer available so that,
    <your_button>.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
```

Enjoy Programming !

Answer (score 0):

simple thing when you tap on the uibutton make an action for that and in the action for that button , you can set the button state to selected and then in the next line of code you can call that method (action)

```
- (IBAction)btn1Touched:(id)sender {
    [_btn2 setSelected:YES];
    [self btn2Touched:self];
}
- (IBAction)btn2Touched:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"btn Action called");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this,'

```
 -(IBAction)nextbutton:(id)sender{
    UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:tagValue];//pass tag value of that particuler button
    btn.selected=YES;
    //do whatevr you want.

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

UIbutton has state called `selected` and it is managed via property `selected`

so to make a button to selected state

```
[buttonInstance setSelected:YES];
```

To make it unselected use

```
[buttonInstance setSelected:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly write a function for that button action like,

```
-(void)Buttonaction

{

do your action here

  also set your button has selected state.

  buttonname.setselected=yes;

}
```

call this function while you are tabbing your button.

Answer (score 0):

Do This:

```
-(IBAction)switchButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{

    if(sender.isSelected)
      {
        .....
      }
    else
      {
        ...
      }
    [sender setSelected:!sender.isSelected];//This will work as Switch.
}
```

> set `Selected(Switch ON)` and `default(Switch OFF)` property (image and title) of `UIButton` from `XIB`, OR from Code as you want.
>   With a single button you can do you functionality with this code