# Xcode Storyboard Simulator test

Tags: ios, xcode7, xcode-storyboard

Is there a way to test views individually from storyboard in Xcode. For example I want to test my last view that is part of navigation controller directly on simulator by passing the prior ones.

I am using Xcode 7.2.

Comment: I really don't understand what you want to test. Do you mean UI testing via using XCTest or not?

Comment: Yes, I want test the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [XcTest](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/04-writing_tests.html) also check out [this article](https://www.objc.io/issues/15-testing/xctest/) on XcTest.

If you are looking to do Behavioral Driven-Development, like navigating through a Navigation stack of segues, like a user would, you can programmatically add Touch events etc in your XCTests:

[how to programmatically fake a touch event to a UIButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028734/how-to-programmatically-fake-a-touch-event-to-a-uibutton)

With XcTest you can see what UI elements are visible, what .text values they have, for example.

If you trying to quickly get to a particular view, so you can see how it looks, without navigating to that view every time the only thing I can think of is to use "Is Initial View Controller" for the UIView and mock any data that might need to be passed to that View to display it properly:

[image]