# programmatically tap UIButton swift

Tags: swift, uibutton, akswiftslidemenu

**Direct Question:**

How do you programmatically tap a UIButton in Swift 2.0?

Example: `UIButton.tap()`

**Explanation as to why i cannot call button click function directly:**

I am currently using AKSwiftSlideMenu (https://github.com/ashishkakkad8/AKSwiftSlideMenu) (https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/akswiftslidemenu) to create a menu. This is accomplished by adding the menu view controller to the main view controller as a child view.

```
let menuVC : BackTableViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("backTableViewController") as! BackTableViewController
    menuVC.btnMenu = sender

    self.view.addSubview(menuVC.view)
    self.addChildViewController(menuVC)
```

As you can see, the `btnMenu`, which is a `UIButton`, is being passed to the `menuVC`. Having the same button on both view controllers allows for a single `onSlideMenuButtonPressed(sender : UIButton)` function in the home view controller  to handle the presentation of the `menuVC`. One of the options in the menu i am creating is the "Log out" button that presents a `UIAlertViewController` which ask if the user wants to sign out. The following is my code for my "Yes" button handler in the `menuVC`:

```
        logOutAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"Yes", style: .Default, handler:  { action in 
        self.btnMenu.touchInside
        CURRENT_USER.unauth()
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(nil, forKey: "uid")
        print("User logged out")
        CurrentUser.checkIfUserIsLoggedIn()
    }))
```

I am attempting to tap the button with the `touchInside` method (which is not right of course) in order to dismiss the `menuVC` . Is there such thing as a `UIButton.tap()` equivalent or a way to access the `btnMenu` `onSlideMenuButtonPressed(sender : UIButton)` function?

**Side Note:**
I played with the idea of creating a homeViewControllerDelegate object for the `menuVC` to call the `onSlideMenuButtonPressed(sender : UIButton)` directly, which might work, but it seems like a round about way seeing as the `btnMenu` already has a reference to that function.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

have you tried:

```
myAutomatedButton.sendActionsForControlEvents(.TouchUpInside)
```

This appears to be a previous question and a possible duplicate, but the post I found was: [how to programmatically fake a touch event to a UIButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028734/how-to-programmatically-fake-a-touch-event-to-a-uibutton)

+1 for swift 3/4 below: @Eneko Alonso

Comment: Super. glad I could help.

Comment: `myAutomatedButton.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)` on Swift 3/4

Answer (score 2):

Also with `@IBAction` defined can just call it :

```
@IBAction func myButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // do something
}

func otherMethod() {
   self.myButtonAction(UIButton())
}
```