# Can the click method in XCUIElement be used outside of the testing framework?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I would like to click an element without user input. I see it's possible in XCUIElement which is a part of the XCTest framework to ensure things are working correctly, and I'm aware of various other testing frameworks that support E2E testing with simulated clicks. But is it possible to trigger this in production outside of testing? E.g. How app remotes work for a TV - pressing a button on the app will move right, left, or click an object on the TV (only remove the TV from this question and have it target the OS it's running on)

Answer (score 0):

It seems accessing other apps might not be possible - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/698795?login=true

But they did recommend a way to programmatically click a button that was found in another stack overflow post here - [how to programmatically fake a touch event to a UIButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028734/how-to-programmatically-fake-a-touch-event-to-a-uibutton)