# Swift - programmatically click on point in screen

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uitouch

**tl;dr-** How can I programmatically perform a native touch in specific point on the screen?

Within the web view there is HTML that contains an Iframe, so the web view code and elements are not accessible and sanding massages to JS is not possible either. There is a button in the web view on specific coordinates. How can I press it programmatically?

Comment: Can you please provide more info on what you want and what you have tried now ?

Comment: Without private API, I think that you can't. Except that you call directly the function (or delegate) that handles the touch.

Comment: And unless what you want to do is in a Test scheme. In that case, you can use some framework like KIF to do that

Comment: @MayankModi, I have button on a webview. I know where the button is specifically located and I need to programmatically press it, but I can't access the webview code. So I want to simulate a touch. (Updated the question)

Comment: Why could you not scan the subviews of the page and look for one at the appropriate coordinate?

Comment: Why do you need to detect button ? you can use delegate methods ? Can you please describe what exact you want ?

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4034034/5654848). This is the swift version if you want: `buttonObj.sendActionsForControlEvents(.TouchUpInside)` .

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am looking for it with no luck. Please elaborate if your problem solved.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to simulate the touch on the JavaScript level, you can use [this extension](https://github.com/rpetrich/fonemonkey4/blob/master/TouchSynthesis.m) on `UITouch` and `UIEvent`, just bridge it to Swift:

```
func performTouchInView(view: UIView) {
    let touch = UITouch(inView: view)
    let eventDown = UIEvent(touch: touch)

    touch.view!.touchesBegan(eventDown.allTouches()!, withEvent: eventDown)

    touch.setPhase(.Ended)
    let eventUp = UIEvent(touch: touch)

    touch.view!.touchesEnded(eventUp.allTouches()!, withEvent: eventUp)
}
```

Your syntax may vary depending on the version of Swift you use.  I'm doing some forced-unwrapping here but you should get the general idea of what is happening.

Comment: @Luda did you add the extension to your application through a bridging header?

Comment: @Luda Looking at the [UITouch private header](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UITouch.h), I see that there are ivars that handle the position of the touch: `_locationInWindow `, `_preciseLocationInWindow`, etc.  You could try overriding `_setLocation:preciseLocation:inWindowResetPreviousLocation:` or `_setLocationInWindow:resetPrevious:` to explicitly set a touch point.  Just expose those interfaces in the Objective-C file.

Comment: @Luda I didn't translate the extension.  The extension adds additional methods on UITouch and UIEvent.  If you bridge to Swift, that is what the implementation of the extension would look like.  To override the other methods I mentioned, just expose them in the interface extension.

Comment: @Luda you added both the `TouchSynthesis.h` and `TouchSynthesis.m` files to your project?  I can't reproduce the issue, I just created an empty Swift project and was able to compile the code in my answer no problem.

Comment: What is `performTouchLeftInView`?  Oh I see, that's a class method on `UIEvent`, not `UITouch`.  Use `UIEvent.performTouchLeftInView(someView)`.

Comment: @Luda I have and am not experieincing any issues.  Here's what I did: 1. Create a new single view Swift application. 2. Add a bridging header 3. Add `TouchSynthesis.h` and `TouchSynthesis.m` to the project 4. add `#import "TouchSynthesis.h"` to bridging header. 5. Add Swift code in my answer to a view controller.

Comment: @Luda I should also note that I am using Xcode 7.3.1 with Swift 2.2.

Comment: Jal, I tried to reproduce your steps till 4 and built.  1. Create a new single view Swift application. 2. Add a bridging header 3. Add TouchSynthesis.h and TouchSynthesis.m to the project 4. add #import "TouchSynthesis.h" to bridging header.. Then I built it and it didn't compile.

Comment: There is a reference to this code here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1975901/1341180 and you can see people saying it is not compiling as well. Maybe you can upload your sample protect to GitHub

Comment: @Luda you're right.  I was using this in a cocoapods project and while it was compiling, it was crashing at runtime.  Tried adding this to an empty project and got a bunch of compilation errors.  Not sure why.  Still investigating...

Comment: Would an app using this get through Apple's app submission process though?

Answer (score 3):

To simulate the touch you will need to write a javascript function in your web page that can click the button on your behalf.

Let's assume the button on the website loaded in the iFrame is coded as the following:

```
<a href="#" id="MagicButton" onclick="targetFunction();">Click Me!</a>
```

And the iFrame is coded like so in your webpage:

```
<iframe id="MyIFrame" src="http://www.stackoverflow.com" width="200" height="200"></iframe>
```

In your web page add the following javascript function to call the click event on the embedded button:

```
<script>
    function myJavaScriptFunction(){
        //get handle for the iFrame element
        var iFrame = document.getElementById('MyIFrame');
        var htmlDoc = iFrame.contentDocument ? iFrame.contentDocument : iFrame.contentWindow.document;
        var magicButton = htmlDoc.getElementById('MagicButton');
        magicButton.click();
    }
</script>
```

Going back to your Swift code, you will need to use the following API:

```
func evaluateJavaScript(_ javaScriptString: String,
      completionHandler completionHandler: ((AnyObject?,
                                 NSError?) -> Void)?)
```

You can execute your javascript function by calling the following function after the page has loaded:

```
   myWKWebview.evaluateJavaScript("myJavaScriptFunction(argument1, argument2);",
                                                               completion:{ _ in })
```

Comment: I don't have access to the JS at all. It is encoded for security reasons. The solution has to be iOS native only

Answer (score 2):

So the objective was to simulate a touch screen event on a webView.

The structure is

```
ViewController-
  self.glassView-|
     self.webView-|
       self.view.
```

I've write this class but I don't yet test:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var glassView: UIView!
    var portionRect: CGRect!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.webView.delegate = self
        let url = NSURL (string: "http://www.tiscali.it");
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        self.webView.loadRequest(requestObj)
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // UIWebViewDelegate

    func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    }


    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        if self.webView.loading {
            return
        } else {
            simulateTap()
        }
    }

    func webView(webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError?) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    }

    func simulateTap() {
        let pointOnTheScreen = CGPointMake(156.0, 506.6)
         self.glassView.hitTest(pointOnTheScreen, withEvent: nil)
         self.glassView.overlapHitTest(pointOnTheScreen, withEvent: nil)            
         print("tap on screen")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let touchLocation = touch.locationInView(self.view)
            print("point touched: \(touchLocation)")
        }
        super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent:event)
    }
}

extension UIView {
    func overlapHitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        // 1
        if !self.userInteractionEnabled || self.hidden || self.alpha == 0 {
            return nil
        }
        //2
        var hitView: UIView? = self
        if !self.pointInside(point, withEvent: event) {
            if self.clipsToBounds {
                return nil
            } else {
                hitView = nil
            }
        }
        //3
        for subview in self.subviews.reverse() {
            let insideSubview = self.convertPoint(point, toView: subview)
            if let sview = subview.overlapHitTest(insideSubview, withEvent: event) {
                return sview
            }
        }
        return hitView
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: you are setting up a tap gesture recognizer and then responding to it in the handleTap function. But how do you invoke the tap?

Comment: You want to invoke automatically or by manual tapping (addTarget)?

Comment: I want to invoke tap programmatically

Comment: I've totally rewrite my answer cause I've misunderstanding what do you want to achieve. I dont yet test this class, let me know if it can help.

Answer (score 0):

You also try hit test:

```
    let pointOnTheScreen = CGPointMake(50, 50)
    view.hitTest(pointOnTheScreen, withEvent: nil)
```

Comment: Found this explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4961484/1341180 Not sure how this can help me...